# MySQL table data size after modifying columns

Tags: mysql

I've got the following situation: I want to transform a poorly constructed (and populated) MySQL table into a more space efficient one. My current table has around 60 columns, all of which are `VARCHAR(40)`. Most of the values are sensor readings and therefore numeric. Currently, the size of this table is 384MB, which I compute using the following query

```sql
SELECT TABLE_NAME AS `Table`, 
        ROUND((DATA_LENGTH + INDEX_LENGTH) / 1024 / 1024) AS `Table size (MB)`
FROM information_schema.TABLES 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = '<mytable>' 
ORDER BY (DATA_LENGTH + INDEX_LENGTH) DESC;
```

I then alter the table by modifying a column I know contains integer values into integer type using

```sql
 ALTER IGNORE TABLE <mytable> MODIFY COLUMNNAME INTEGER;
```

this correctly converts all values to `INT(11)` and reduced the table to 299MB. This is way more that I anticipated. Doing this for more columns generally keeps decreasing the table size, however for some, it drastically increases the size. For example, I reduced the table to 278MB, then converted a column from `VARCHAR(40)` to `INT(11)` and obtained a size of 398MB, more than what I had when starting off.

Looking for an explanation, I found that MySQL stores varchar types in L + 1 bytes (L being the length of the string). `INT(11)` consists of 4 bytes. Some columns contain many 0s, so I was not surprised to see that the total size would go up slightly for some columns as the average size per entry would increase marginally. However, the effects are way more drastic than I would expect.

I am curious if there is some detail about how MySQL organises the data that explains this behaviour, any ideas?

I am using MariaDB (latest) locally.

(note that I'm not necessarily concerned in the performance increase of queries and inserts for this question in particular)

Comment: Incidentally, the number in parentheses after an INT declaration is fairly meaningless, and probably best omitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`INT` always takes 4 bytes.  Consider on `MEDIUMINT`, which takes 3 bytes and has a range of +/-8M.  See also SMALLINT and TINYINT.

Consider appending `UNSIGNED`.  For example, `MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED` takes 3 bytes also and holds between 0 and 16M.

In a `VARCHAR(40)`

```
'1' takes 2 bytes (length plus 1 character)
'1234' takes 5 bytes
'12.3' takes 5 bytes
etc.
```

And also consider DECIMAL:

`DECIMAL(3, 1)` can hold up to +/-99.9 in 2 bytes
`DECIMAL(4, 2)` can hold up to +/-99.99 in 2 bytes

The formula for space for Decimal is a bit complex.  A simple estimate is to divide the first number by 2.

`FLOAT` is always 4 bytes and can hold about 7 significant digits, with a modest range of exponent.

To do a decent job of shrinking, pick the suitable datatype for each column.

On top of what the data takes, there is a significant amount of overhead -- for the column, for the row, for the block, etc.  Plan on multiplying any estimate of space by 3 for InnoDB.  Also, the actual size (as computed from that `information_schema` query will fluxuate as data is added/updated.  But also keep in mind, the disk space consumed can only increase.  That is, deleting rows will not shrink the disk space.

The `(11)` on `INT` is meaningless and has been removed in 8.0.xx.

**Fluctuation**

There are a lot of causes of the size of the table to fluxuate.

- Random inserts lead to more fragmentation
- Updating a row rarely leads to increasing or decreasing the allocation size.
- When the size increases, it is usually by 16KB for small tables or a small number of megabytes for a large table.
- Many ALTERs require rebuilding a table.  The *may* lead to decreasing the disk allocation -- due to not copying over the fragmented space.
- Each secondary index acts like a table (both are BTrees).  The change in space for each index depends on whether it is rebuilt or incrementally modified.
- Altering the data type of a column or columns probably requires copying all the data over, then rebuilding the indexes.

Comment: Is there a reason for this fluctuation? This is what I'm looking to find out. Why does MySQL/InnoDB generate this behaviour? Might it have to do with page allocation?

Comment: @Robbin - I added a bunch of hand-waving on fluctuations.

Comment: That's actually really insightful, thanks!